# Matching values multiple columns in one dataframe with values in multip

Tags: r, dataframe, match, mapply

I have two dataframes, and I am trying to transfer information from one to the other, based on conditions in multiple columns:

```
  df1 = data.frame("Name" = c("John", "Jake", "John", "Jake"), "Date" = c("2020-01-03", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"))

    df1
Name       Date
1 John 2020-01-03
2 Jake 2020-01-02
3 John 2020-01-03
4 Jake 2020-01-04

df2 = data.frame("Name" = c("John", "Jake", "John", "Jake"), "Date" = c("2020-01-03", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-04"), "NewData" = c("Stuff1", "Stuff2", "Stuff3", "Stuff4"))

df2
  Name       Date NewData
1 John 2020-01-03  Stuff1
2 Jake 2020-01-01  Stuff2
3 John 2020-01-01  Stuff3
4 Jake 2020-01-04  Stuff4
```

I'd like to create a new column, `df1$NewData.copied`, which would get the data from `df2$NewData` if there is a match of names `(df1$Name == df2$Name)` and a comparison of a date `(df1$Date > df2$Date)`.

At the end, df1 will look like:

```
  Name       Date NewData.copied
1 John 2020-01-03         Stuff3
2 Jake 2020-01-02         Stuff2
3 John 2020-01-03         Stuff3
4 Jake 2020-01-04           <NA>
```

(or `""` instead of `NA`).

I need to keep all the observations in `df1`, whether there is a match or not.

I've tried using `%in%` and match+mapply, but I keep getting `"longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter"` arguments.

Comment: I think you are describing a join, and in particular a left non-equi join. You can do this using the `data.table` package, or using the latest development version of the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Thank you - that's it! Although I wish the non-equi join for dplyr supported %in% conditions as well.